# how to get current running code line and directory name in go

Tags: go

i`m looking for a way to get current working directory plus the very line which is running, in a string variable to be stored or printed like :

```
./dir/working_file.go:29
```

i have used *os.Getwd( )* but it just gets the file name. line is missing.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Working directory and source code don't necessarily have any relationship to each other.

Comment: You should very well understand that Go is not a scripting language. Even if you're using `go run` (and if you do, please stop, for multiple reasons) the code is first compiled into an executable image file which is then executed. So those "current file and line number" are purely virtual things at the time a compiled Go program runs: they are kept in the so-called debugging information which is present in the executable image file mostly to help debugging: when the Go runtime crashes the running program, it wants to dump usefully-looking stack traces of the executing goroutines.

Comment: To say the same in other words: when a Go program is being executed, there's no such things as the current file and the current line number: what's being executed is either [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code)—for "native" builds—or bytecode for platforms such as [WASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly). To recap, Go code is not normally "interpreted"—as in bash or Python, and when the compiled program runs, no source code is read from files.

Comment: thanks for your attention on this subject. im partially aware of how the code turns to a binary for execution, but currently im working on a log collecting system that this virtual data can really helps me with it